# Find tr tag with particular style using jquery

Tags: jquery

So i was working on this table using jquery.Html for the table with single tr is as below 
I want to first fetch the tr tag which is having style sheet and once that is done i want to get value of particular td in it which i am able to do if there is one tr in a table like in the below html

```
    <table id="tblTowerSubTowerLot" class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-5">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Tower Name</th>
            <th>Sub Tower Name</th>
            <th>Lot Name</th>
            <th>Derived Resource</th>
            <th style="width: 75px;">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr id="trTSL0" class="pricingRow" onclick="SetLotwiseDataControls(0);" style="background-color: rgba(217, 244, 252, 1);"><td style="display:none;"><label id="lblClientFTEDetailsId0">8893</label><label id="lblDealId0">6804</label><label id="lblTowerId0">1</label><label id="lblSubTowerId0">1</label><label id="lblLotId0">1</label></td><td><label id="lblTowerName0" class="pricingRow m-0">T1</label></td><td><label id="lblSubTowerName0" class="pricingRow m-0">ST1</label></td><td><label id="lblLotName0" class="pricingRow m-0">1</label></td><td><label id="lblDerivedFTE0" class="pricingRow m-0">1.04</label></td><td><img id="imgStaffIndicator0" src="../Content/Custom/images/Staffing_tick.png" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Staffing Completed" style="width: 22px;"><img id="imgPriceIndicator0" src="../Content/Custom/images/Pricing_untick.png" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pricing Pending" style="width: 22px;"></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

For this i am able to fetch the value of particular td tag by

```
if( $('#tblTowerSubTowerLotPricing tbody tr').attr('style') ) 
  {

    $("td label:eq(3)").html();

  } 
else 
  {

    console.log('It did not equal block');

  }
```

image for the same is [image: For single td]

but now when there are multiple tr in the table and if 3rd or 4th tr is selected like in the image below
[image: Multiple tr with one of it consisting of style sheet]

and i try to use the code

```
if( $('#tblTowerSubTowerLotPricing tbody tr').attr('style') ) 
  {

    $("td label:eq(3)").html();

  } 
else 
  {

    console.log('It did not equal block');

  }
```

Then it goes in the else part and i am not able to fetch the data.

How can i fetch the data when there are multiple tr tags and only one of them has style applied to it.

Comment: in your style is background color common or different?

Comment: Hi. Its common. this is the only background color that will be used and it is used to show that one particular tr tag is active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, your selector matches multiple elements, so you should parse each of them using the `.each` jQuery method.

When doing so, you want to select the `td` that is a child of the element, so you use the `.find` jQuery method.

```
$('#tblTowerSubTowerLotPricing tbody tr').each(function(index, element) {
  if ($(element).attr('style') {
    console.log($(element).find("td label:eq(3)").html());
  } else {
    console.log('It did not equal block');
  }
});
```

The documentation for these methods may help you further.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `style` attr it will works check this example

`if( $('#tblTowerSubTowerLotPricing').attr('style') == 'background-color:rgba(217,244,252,1);')`

```js
if( $('#tblTowerSubTowerLotPricing').attr('style') == 'background-color:rgba(217,244,252,1);') {
      alert('It equal block');
     
} else {
      alert('It did not equal block');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tblTowerSubTowerLotPricing" style="background-color:rgba(217,244,252,1);">Test</div>
```